# Passing url parameter on django modelform attributes

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

I need to create a form with 5 select fields, each one dependent of the previous one (Schools, Disciplines, Macro-Content, Micro-Content, Teacher)

I'm able to get only one working, passing an Ajax view to the form div:

```
  <form action="" id="orderForm" method="POST" discipline-queries-url="{% url 'ajax-load-discipline' %}>
```

and

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("#institute").change(function () {
        const url = $("#orderForm").attr("discipline-queries-url");
        const instituteId = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {
                'institute_id': instituteId
            },
            success: function (data) { 
                $("#discipline").html(data);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

From what I understand I'd need 4 different ajax views, one for each database query, and pass the url attribute through modelform attributes like this:

```
            'discipline': forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'discipline', 'class': 'form-control',
                                              'discipline-queries-url': '{% url "ajax-load-discipline" %}'}),
```

But the special characters are escaping and returning something like this:

```
"GET /order/create/%7B%%20url%20%22ajax-load-discipline%22%20%%7D?institute_id=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 13568
```

So it is passing {% url "ajax-load-discipline" %} to the url...

Any idea of what I can do to pass the correct parameters?

Comment: Ok, I made it work passing the full URL direct to the ajax javascript:                                                  url: 'http://localhost:8000/ajax/load-discipline-details/', BUT OH BOY this looks wrong. Any idea how to make it work direct by django templatetags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set attributes for a widget, it does not get rendered as if it were part of the template, it gets rendered as if it were a variable being rendered in the template, hence instead of `"{% url 'ajax-load-discipline' %}"` you should be writing the url itself there using [`reverse_lazy` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy):

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


'discipline': forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'discipline', 'class': 'form-control', 'discipline-queries-url': reverse_lazy('ajax-load-discipline')}),
```